# Multiple regex expressions to check mobile number in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

Hi all i have a condition to test international phone number patterns that is(###) ###-####,Currently i have written code for this patter,which is working fine,But i want to allow a pattern also (###)###-#### and it should not accept letters but currently it is accepting,Can somebody please helpme how to achieve this

```
const phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phone_number').value.trim();

    // Regex pattern for USA phone number
    const pattern = /^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}$/;

    // Validate phone number and update message
    const isValid = pattern.test(phoneNumber);
    document.getElementById('phoneValidationMsg').textContent = isValid ? '' : 'Please enter a valid phone number.';
    return isValid;
```

Comment: `?` matches a pattern 1 or 0 times. So just add it, `const pattern = /^\(\d{3}\) ?\d{3}-\d{4}$/`

Answer (score -1):

Try the below regular expression:

```
^\(\d{3}\)\s?\d{3}-\d{4}
```

I added the "\s?" to the regular expression. It checks for an optional space.

Comment: Hi, Thanks its working now with/without space,But its accepting letters, It should allow only numbers and () these characters

Comment: The `\d` should only test against numbers, not letters. Can you give an example of a string with letters which is passing the regular expression?